# Styling using Javascript Cookie

Tags: javascript, css

I seem to be able to retrieve the value of the cookie but the style of the corresponding ID isn't changed. What am I missing?

```
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieName = document.cookie;
        var prefix = name + "=";
        var begin = cookieName.indexOf("; " + prefix);
        if (begin == -1) {
            begin = cookieName.indexOf(prefix);
            if (begin != 0) return null;
        } else begin += 2;
        var end = cookieName.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) end = cookieName.length;
        return unescape(cookieName.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    }
    var value = getCookie('nameCookie');
    document.getElementById(value).style.height = "10%";
```

following code also doesn't work

```
    var value = getCookie('nameCookie');
    if (value == 'test') {
          document.getElementById('test').style.height = "10%";
    }
```

Comment: If you console.log(value) does it contains the ID you are expecting

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com, he say `he seems to have retrieved the value`

Comment: Missed that, try console.log(document.getElementById(value)); What kind of Element is it? Is it a block element, can it have 10% height? is the parent height defined so the browser can calculate 10%?

Comment: The element is an image of which the original size is 5%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you `seem to be able to retrieve the value of the cookie`
the problem is that when the code is running, it cannot find the element because the DOM is not ready yet. Make sure the script is running, after the element is loaded.

Just place your script block just before closing the `</body>`.

Comment: doesn't seem to be any difference

Comment: Good call! Spoiled by my own coding habits was not even thinking about if the dom was ready!

Comment: @TimD'Haene, Do you have an element with `id` what the cookies values is?

Comment: yes, even if I changed the getElementById to getElementById('idName') and put the whole thing in an if statement, it still isn't working

Comment: @TimD'Haene, Paste your html on pastebin and post the link on your post. I want to take a look at it.

Comment: something I seem to notice in the above code is that the first document.write is shown but the second one (in the if statement) isn't

Comment: Yes, that is because the JS fails because document.getElementById('stopcontacten') is null. You can't get an element before it is being added to the DOM. Exactly as Stax pointed out above, you need to include the JS AFTER you actually create the HTML, preferably before the closing body tag.

Comment: @TimD'Haene, It was logical mistake. The setcookie part is in the `onclick` of the img. When it is called the getCookie, will have already ran and not found anything. Try this [paste](http://pastebin.com/AibQ6QYT). I have triggered the function once again and added the script to the end, as i told you in my answer.

Comment: @TimD'Haene, who are responding to. Please Do not confuse us. And Incude `@` to comment a certain person and use their name instead

Comment: @TimD'Haene, Great. Now make sure whenever you are running that code, the code is able to find the element on the DOM

Comment: @TimD'Haene, Just reminding you to accept the answer, once it works. :-)